# Is there some Java library for converting .svg to .png or .jpg at code?

Tags: java, svg

Is there some Java library for converting .svg to .png or .jpg at code ? Does anybody have experience with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifically, you should take a look at the [Batik Rasterizer](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html).

Here are the associated JavaDocs for manipulating it at the code level:

- http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/
- http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/apps/rasterizer/package-frame.html

Answer (score 12):

Check out [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), which has an Apache license.