# How to convert .vsd file to .pdf or .xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, aspose

I have one vsd file i want to convert that into pdf or xml  file using java code .

How to convert vsd to pdf or xml in java

Comment: Obviously: `Java.convertVsdToPdf();`

Comment: thanks for reply   Andremoniy . can u pls giv full explanation of it i mean full java code for this .

Comment: Sorry, no. It is `native` method.

Comment: The question is pretty badly written, but in the interests of trying to help - take a look at http://poi.apache.org/hdgf/ for how to read the file in and iText to dump it out to PDF. That said, your requirements of PDF or XML seem a little strange. Probably best opening it in Visio and just printing to a PDF using CutePDF or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aspose claims](https://products.aspose.com/diagram/java) to support this ([example](https://github.com/asposediagram/Aspose_Diagram_Java/blob/master/Examples/src/main/java/com/aspose/diagram/examples/Diagrams/ExportToPDF.java)).

[POI has component](http://poi.apache.org/hdgf/) for reading visio files, but not rendering them.

This [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600566/visio-to-svg-converter) here on stack overflow contains a bunch to tools for outputing SVG which should be [easyish to turn into a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875807/convert-svg-to-pdf).

All of this is from a quick Google search for `java render visio`