# SVG to PDF. How to?

Tags: android, svg, itext, batik, itextg

I'm trying to output an SVG file into a PDF. I've tried a few approaches, but I keep running into problems.

I used this source as reference:
[Convert SVG to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875807/convert-svg-to-pdf)
and tried the following:

```
// Save this SVG into a file (required by SVG -> PDF transformation process)
File svgFile = File.createTempFile("graphic-", ".svg");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
DOMSource source2 = new DOMSource(svgXmlDoc);
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(svgFile);
try { transformer.transform(source2, new StreamResult(fOut)); }
finally { fOut.close(); }

// Convert the SVG into PDF
File outputFile = File.createTempFile("result-", ".pdf");
SVGConverter converter = new SVGConverter();
converter.setDestinationType(DestinationType.PDF);
converter.setSources(new String[] { svgFile.toString() });
converter.setDst(outputFile);
converter.execute();
```

I ran into several ClassNotFoundExceptions, mostly related to batik.DOM, which is really strange, since I can see it listed in the external libraries.

Next, I tried using iTextG. I followed the code in SvgToPdf: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15

But then I get stuck, as iTextG does not have PdfGraphics2D, and that method requires it.

Any idea on how can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up going with, which does rely on any libraries.

The WebKit engine can render an SVG, so you can load an SVG into a WebView:

```
webView.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(svgFile).toString());
```

WebView also has the ability to print, so then you can continue with:

```
// Get a PrintManager instance
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

// Get a print adapter instance
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

// Create a print job with name and adapter instance
String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
        new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```