# JAVA: SVG to JPG converter

Tags: java, svg, png, converters, batik

is there any libraries to convert **SVG** to **JPG** ? else than **BATIK** ?
i used **BATIK** but i found some problems like this exception :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:684)
>       at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:755)
>       at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:96)
>       at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertDisplay(CSSUtilities.java:509)
>       at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:176)
>       at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:148)
>       at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
>       at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:165)
>       at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:86)
>       at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:132)

this is my code :

```
          JPEGTranscoder transcoder = new JPEGTranscoder();

      transcoder.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_CLASSNAME,
          "org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl");
      transcoder.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
          new Float(1.0));

      TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream("C:/Taha/SmartPlannerNew/rectangles.svg"));
      OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Taha/SmartPlannerNew/out.jpg");
      TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

      try {
        transcoder.transcode(input, output);
    } catch (TranscoderException e) { 
        System.out.println("error***************************************************************************************************************************");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("done.");
      ostream.close();
      System.exit(0);
```

can any one help me please ?

Comment: You should focus on Batik - see this question - [Is there some Java library for converting .svg to .png or .jpg at code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610792/is-there-some-java-library-for-converting-svg-to-png-or-jpg-at-code)? . Probably, you can get Batik to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my mistake was that i was using different versions of jar files  i deleted all my jars and downloaded a new set of jars from the same

Comment: I was getting `NullPointerException` as well while transcoding from input to output, debugging API I found out that only `batik-transcoder` jar was not enough and I needed to add `batik-codec` jar to fix

Answer (score 5):

***Batik is exactly what you are looking for, is totally stable, and there really is not much else.***

You can read the handy official tutorial on using the transcoder portion of batik:
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html

If you are still having trouble, try posting the code that you are using that causes the error, and a complete stack trace.  Somebody here will be able to help you.

Comment: Sometimes JAR files can be a mess.  In the future you might look at a managed build system like Apache Maven, or a dependency manager like Apache Ivy.